# ApiController accept the json in POST on the localhost testing server, but not on the production server. Why?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-6

I have been struggling with this for two days. It is so discouraging.

It is a relatively simple api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Save(ReportCreateInputModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        _service.AddReport(model);

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when debugging on localhost:xxxx. The model is valid and a new record can be inserted into the database.

But when it is published to the server, I always get a `400: Bad Request`. I have tried different browser and am pretty sure it is a server side issue.

Then I tried increase the request size as mentioned in some other posts. But it still cannot work. I could not install remote debugging tool on that server.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Is it something with IIS 6?

I really appreciate any assistance. Thank you!

---

Update:

It turns out the api POST action is never hit before the `Bad Request` error is thrown. But why it is fine in local debugging?

---

Update:

I have added these lines of code in WebApiConfig.cs

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
    Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

Now in the `jqXHR.responseText` I have an exception

```
"$id":"3","Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.",
"ExceptionType":"System.PlatformNotSupportedException",
"StackTrace":" at System.Web.HttpContext.get_CurrentNotification()
               at System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.get_CurrentNotification()
               at GetCurrentNotification(Object )
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)"
```

Wow! Is it something to do with IIS 6 I am using? Who can tell me what that StackTrace is? Thanks.

---

Now I find out in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.currentnotification%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that it is `get_CurrentNotification` that requires the pipeline thing, which exists only in IIS7. But who can tell us where have I made calls to `HttpContext.CurrentNotification`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to this instead to see why you are getting a bad request,

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
```

You should always include ModelState in your response if you are returning a 400 due to invalid ModelState. That way the clients would have information on what is wrong with their request.

Also, if possible, just for debugging, enable IncludeExceptionDetails always by doing this on your configuration. That way you can get more details in your 400 error response.

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

Remember that you should IncludeExceptionDetails always only for debugging on production servers. Otherwise, you would be leaking security sensitive information to everyone who can access your service which is bad.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But where is the place for `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy`. In Global.asax?

Comment: Actually I found the POST action has never been hit. How come the post can reach the action in localhost:xxx but not in the production server?

Comment: yes. you could configure IncludeErrorDetailPolicy in your global.asax or may be in `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`